# Chrome extension: Multiple tabs in popup window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, popup

1. I was wondering if there is a way to divide the popup window into more than one tab, when each tab functions as a different web page, using chrome extension APIs. Does somebody know if that's possible?
2. If I can't do that, I thought I will give up the division into separate web pages and just use tabs on the same web page, like UI tabs for example.
   Can you suggest a third way?

Comment: I think Chrome's tabs are complete independent of each other as they each run as a separate process. You'll probably have to open a single window with html tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Browser`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)\[`Page`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html) Action [Windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#popups) are [`Windows of type Popup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window), you cannot add further tabs to the popup window.

As pointed out using some sort of [`UI Tabs`](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) will solve your problem. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement the internal tabs (not browser tabs), if I'll encounter problems I'll open another post.

Comment: can you provide more information or how you resolve the problem @Subway

Comment: @RaihanRidoy, in case it's still relevant, I created one single page and used tabs within the page, like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) or [this](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/).
I couldn't find a way to have the popup window containing different web pages as in an internet browser.